# Pythonic way to work with abstract classes

Tags: python, design-patterns

I am new to python, coming from C++ land. Have a question about pythonic way of designing something.

I want to provide an abstraction layer for some functionality. Attempting to do it with the `ABC` module. Then, having a base class like so:

```python
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class AbstractBase(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def method(self):
        pass
```

I would ALSO want to pass some non-abstract-like arguments to child classes, e.g.:

```python
class Child(AbstractBase):
    def method(self, arg):
        pass
```

This seems to work fine, but it technically speaking breaks the substitution principle. And it will break even further if I start using the `typing` module.

So question - in the C++ land I would solve this with another class serving as a factory to create such objects, but would true Pythonistas do the same? Or are there other ways of dealing with this?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how the C solution would work, but what's the point of declaring an abstractmethod in the first place when you don't have a fixed signature for it?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'd bother with your current declaration of `AbstractBase` at all, just assume all is OK.  if you want `typing` to do the right thing, you could make `arg` a keyword only argument in the base class

Comment: Ok, I see, I wasn't clear enough :( I wrote one of the options (which looks quite weird to me to be honest :) ). The other option could be to have the same method signature, but take this argument in the `__init__` method. To then maintain this abstraction layer, I would create a factory that can create these objects (with correct arguments passed in) and clients could call the `method` without any worries

Comment: Adding a C++ example could have helped to get your point across. As others have mentioned, the code proposed in the question looks weird. And it's not clear to me what drives the need to create "another class serving as a factory to create such objects", given the little context you've provided.